# PMD - Java 8 - Law of demeter

Tags: java, java-8, maven-3, pmd

I use PMD plugin in my Maven project to verify code violations and standards. In Java-8, the PMD complains the below code as `Potential violation of Law of Demeter`.

```
Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4).stream().filter(n -> n % 2 == 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also the `Optional.ofNullable(value).orElse("another")`, and almost all lambda expressions.

However, I have set the below PMD property in the pom.xml

```
<targetJdk>1.8</targetJdk>
<rulesets>
    <ruleset>/category/java/bestpractices.xml</ruleset>
    <ruleset>/category/java/design.xml</ruleset>
    <!-- <ruleset>/category/java/codestyle.xml</ruleset> -->
    <ruleset>/category/java/errorprone.xml</ruleset>
    <ruleset>/category/java/security.xml</ruleset>
    <ruleset>/category/java/multithreading.xml</ruleset>
    <ruleset>/category/java/performance.xml</ruleset>
</rulesets>
```

Did I miss anything in configuration? Any fixes you can propose?

Comment: Perhaps, “Law of Demeter” does not belong to the codestyle rule but one of the other rules?

Comment: It belongs to the design.xml

Answer (score 3):

The rule flags any usage of objects not created locally / received as parameters.

That automatically means all factory methods are flagged (`Arrays.asList`, `Optional.ofNullable`, etc.).

You should either remove the rule from your ruleset (you would need to [define your own ruleset xml](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.10.0/pmd_userdocs_making_rulesets.html)), or deal with the false positives and suppress them either [case by case](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.10.0/pmd_userdocs_suppressing_warnings.html) or [customize the rule's suppression](https://pmd.github.io/pmd-6.10.0/pmd_userdocs_suppressing_warnings.html#xpath-and-regex-message-suppression) (which also need you to define your own ruleset)

Comment: Surprised the PMD doesn't have ruleset to verify the Java-8? Aren't there any customized (opensource) Java-8 Lambda ruleset you can point me to?

Comment: PMD **does** handle lambdas, and is very aware of them (actually PMD support up to java 11). This particular rule just doesn't like factory methods, no problem with lambdas themselves.

Comment: See https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/2160.